# how to kill a program using c++ when that same program is opened twice?

Tags: c++, windows

say, I have a C++ program, Named "A.exe"
If someone opened it twice, 
The program should kill it and then run as One single program.

RULE:It should be killed by that program (NOT by using any other program).

My problem is
if I use

```
system("taskkill /im A.exe /t");
```

but It kills itself too.

Comment: Add the parameter that targets the other process, so the current process is not killed too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Microsoft Windows operating system has a feature called "file locks". You should read up on them, and perhaps see if using them correctly will let you do this.

Comment: It's usually better practice to use a lock file and only allow execution to proceed if the lock file isn't already present. I..e. the second and subsequent executions terminate themselves. Remember to delete the lock file on termination!

Comment: First you say "RULE:It should be killed by that program (NOT by using any other program).". Then you show code doing "system("taskkill /im A.exe /t");" which clearly contradicts the first statement by using a external program to do the job. What do you *actually* need/want?

Comment: well,that code is already written inside that program

Comment: @Aravind .KEN code already being written does not mean code cannot be changed.

Comment: yeah, what changes to be done ? to solve this problem.

Comment: use a named mutex: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682418(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a named mutex, this can only be held by one thread at at time, create it at the beginning of your program, if you fail to acquire the mutex, it is because there is another copy of your program already running (and owning the mutex), you can then safely terminate the program (without having to call any external programs, relying looking for particular file names etc)

Comment: And before having the redundant process exit, have it post a message to the first process's window handle to notify it to come to the foreground.

Comment: @selbie good point - otherwise you risk frustrating your users when it looks like your app won’t start

Comment: Other things to consider: the already-running instance might be hung, or just take a long time exiting. Your current instance might have received command line arguments the user expects to ve handled.